# Debugging my downloader

Tags: c#, .net, exception, httpwebrequest

I have a downloader application in C# using .NET 2.0. For the most people it works well, but I saw that I have big error log from other people. The 99% of the exceptions are:

- Unable to connect to remote server
- The remote name could not be resolved
- Operation timed out

Can this be from a short timeout of my downloader or from a slower internet connection? Or it can be some internal thread error in my downloader (it's multipart/multithread).

Comment: "Remote name could not be resolved" typically indicates a DNS error. Have the user enter the following on a command line:  `nslookup www.servername.com`, where `www.servername.com` is replaced by the host name you're trying to download from. If there's a DNS problem, this command will fail to resolve the name.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some of your users

- are behind a firewall or proxy, which is supported by their web browser but not by your downloader or
- simply have a terribly bad Internet connection.

Comment: The strange part is that most of them write that at first all was ok, after 2-3 days "Unable to connect to remote server".

Comment: @blez: Is that 2-3 days with the program running all the time? Does shutting down the program and restarting it make the problem go away?

Comment: No, not running all the time, also after restarting it doesn't fix it.